# How to take values from a line graph built using angular JS by selenium webdriver c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

I have a graph which is built using angular js.This is what I get when i inspect the graph element.

```
<canvas 
ng-reflect-datasets="[object Object]" 
ng-reflect-labels="blahblah" 
ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" 
ng-reflect-chart-type="line" 
ng-reflect-colors="[object Object]"  
ng-reflect-legend="true">
</canvas>
```

The lines in the graph has proper tooltips with data.
Can someone please guide me how to fetch the values / tooltip values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CANVAS tag is like an applet in the page and does not contain HTML for what is displayed within it so it can't be interacted with normally. You can do things like move the cursor around, click, and hover using [`.MoveToElement(element, offsetX, offsetY)`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions_MoveToElement_1.htm) but it's not deterministic. If the contents change, you won't have any idea because it's all location based and not element based. Your best bet is to talk to the devs, if you have access to them, and get them to build you an API that you can use to access the internals of the CANVAS and do your testing that way.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC for the reply

Answer (score 4):

### in java i use this if you use ChartJS:

```
String javaScript ="var puntos=Chart.instances[0].data.datasets[0].data; return puntos";
String dato=((JavascriptExecutor)DriverContext.getDriver()).executeScript(javaScript).toString();
```

returns a string of all data in the chart(an array).

Answer (score 0):

I just started using ngWebDriver for Java and I know you can use Protractor.NET in C#.

You can get the elements you mentioned ng-* using the ngWebDriver "ByAngular" locator.

For example this is how it looks like for an element like:

```
<select ng-model="operator" class="bla bla"/>

driver.findElement(ByAngular.model("operator"))
```